# Understanding ~きて in おいてきて

Tags: grammar, meaning

```
A：「おいしかったね、あの店。また行こうね。」

B: 「あ！店にけいたい電話おいてきてしまったからとりにもどらないと。」
```

I don't really understand the function or meaning of ~きて here. Could someone help me parse this part grammatically? Why おいてきてしまった instead of おいてしまった?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ~きて means ~来て (to come)

おいてきて（置いて来て) literally means (I put and came here)

Putting it together:

> 店にけいたい電話おいてきてしまった I left my phone at the store (lit. I put my phone at the store and came here unintentionally)

Japanese often indicates the motion following the verb:

ペンを買ってくる - to buy and bring a pen here

トイレに行ってくる - to go to the toilet and come back

[This](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/helping-verbs/) might help you understand.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it was being used in a literal physical sense or time/change based sense. I guess I was overthinking it. The linked article helps a lot!